# AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot with python and I want a select menu for my top command. But when I try to run the command I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zhsos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 1353, in invoke_command
    await func.invoke(ctx, **args)
  File "C:\Users\zhsos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord_slash\model.py", line 210, in invoke
    return await self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\zhsos\OneDrive\Documents\IA bot\python_bot.py", line 505, in _top
    await topselect(ctx)
  File "c:\Users\zhsos\OneDrive\Documents\IA bot\python_bot.py", line 116, in topselect
    top_msg = await ctx.send(embed=top_embed, components=[Select(
  File "C:\Users\zhsos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord_slash\context.py", line 215, in send
    if components and not all(comp.get("type") == 1 for comp in components):
  File "C:\Users\zhsos\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\discord_slash\context.py", line 215, in <genexpr>
    if components and not all(comp.get("type") == 1 for comp in components):
AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I can't find the solution anywhere

This is the function I have:

```
async def topselect(ctx):
    top_msg = await ctx.send(embed=top_embed, components=[Select(
        placeholder='Select',
        options=[
            SelectOption(label='Option 1', value='1')
        ],
        custom_id='topselect'
    )])
    interaction = await client.wait_for('select_option', check=lambda inter:inter.custom_id == topselect and inter.user == ctx.author)
    await interaction.send(interaction.values[0])
```

I want this function (for now) to send the value of the option. Did anyone have this issue who can help me?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the full error traceback, starting at the word "traceback".

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, I don't think "the full error traceback" is needed. I guess you meant the relevant *code* starting from `<Select object>.get()`; please double-check before copy-pasting comments; completely ignore me if the traceback's needed. Also, mek0, please [edit] your question to include relevant code starting from `<Select object (probably 'comp')>.get()` or the creation of `comp`.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder The error occurs in library code, that's why I was looking for the traceback

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs, what do you mean? The current code isn't enough, but the (previous) traceback looks like it's enough.

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder As per the traceback, the error occurs when `ctx.send` is called, and it occurs in `discord_slash`'s handling of components. `<Select object>.get()` is *never called by the OP*, it's library code.